# Помогите написать скрипт, уже какой день не могу логику продумать

Tags: php, html, sql, phpmyadmin

Надо из БД(phpMyAdmin) вытащить значении и сделать так что один из них был checked

http://hkar.ru/Nb56

Comment: картинку в новой вкладке откройте, если не отображается

Comment: Если совершенно любой, то при выводе в цикле можно добавить условие: если переменная цикла = 0, то дописать checked

Comment: пожалуйста, используйте комбинацию клавиш Ctrl+G, что бы добавить картинку в вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала создаем подключение к  БД:

```
<?
$link = mysqli_connect('хост', 'пользователь', 'пароль', 'имя бд');
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo 'Ошибка подключения к БД ('.mysqli_connect_errno().'): '.mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
?>
```

Создаёи функцию, которая при вызове вытаскивает значение типа:

```
function getPosts() {

    global $link;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `таблица твоя` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 21";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    $posts = mysqli_fetch_all ($result, 1) ;
    return $posts;
}
```

Теперь мы ее вызываем и создаём цикл:

```
<?$posts = getPosts();?> 
<? foreach($posts as $post): ?>
Картинка: <?=$post['image']?>
Время: <?=$post['time']?>
И тд
```

В конце завершаем цикл: `<? endforeach; ?>` 
**Вот так ты вытаскиваешь любые значения из БД** Тебе осталось продумать, как вытащить значение checked

Comment: а зачем session_start(); ???

Comment: Да это строчка моего кода просто:) не заметил, исправлю